# how to have blank spaces for android:text attribute value in xml

Tags: android

I had a scenario where I need to have spaces for android:text attribute value.

android:text="Input type"  ---> I need output with 5 spaces between "Input" and "type" Strings 

How can  I achieve the above result.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: your problem is not properly clear..
do you want 5 spaces after first letter end via programmatically ?

Comment: The String "Input Type" should have 5 spaces between them but I see only one white space considered though I give 5 spaces between "Input" and "Type"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/xxx"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/empty_spaces" />
```

in strings.

```
<string name="empty_spaces">Input\t\t type</string>
```

Comment: but the problem it works fine in one and does n't work fine in another device. How can we handle device density in this case

Comment: this will work in all devices, if you want to do it with different devices you can add this in values-hdpi\strings.xml and also in values-mdpi/strings.xml file

Answer (score 1):

You can replace spaces by `\u0020`

```
<TextView android:text="Input\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020types" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use string ressources.

Put all your string value in a file on `res/values/strings.xml`.

If you want to add space you can do it by surround your text by double quotes.

You can see an example in the documentation : 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling

Answer (score 1):

Add this `&#160;` with your strings in xml file

```
<string name="stringsample">Sample:&#160;</string>
```